# What is the difference between a research paper and a student paper?

Tags: conference

The [i-Society conference](http://www.i-society.eu/Important%20Dates.html) calls for Research Papers, Student Papers, and Case Studies.

What is the difference between a "research paper" and a "student paper"?

Comment: It could be that a student paper is for the [special track PhD consortium](http://www.i-society.eu/Special%20Tracks.html). You probably should contact the organisers to have more information.

Comment: In computer science conferences, there is often a "Best student paper" award, which goes to the best paper where all authors are students. But I don't think that's the answer to this question, since this type of "student paper" is never listed separately in the CFP.

Comment: Where in the site it is written these paper formats?

Answer (score 1):

A research paper is original work and could be written by anyone with the background.  A student paper is a research paper written exclusively by student(s).  The reality is that faculty will be involved in some way, even if it is only running the research program which made the work possible.  In reality, the faculty will be more involved than that: discussing, reading and suggesting.  But that's part of the job, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the difference would be in the scope, length and research significance of the paper, basically significant pieces of research compared to smaller pieces of research.
Also research in progress could be submitted as a student paper in some circumstances.

Comment: What information is this answer based on?

Comment: Personal experience submitting academic papers to journals in student or researcher form. http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-parallel-and-distributed-computing/0743-7315/guide-for-authors See the 'Types of Articles' sub-heading. Not called student papers, but research notes which I equate to the same thing.